# IOS IAP not working in released app.

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have just released the 1st Version of my app with 3 auto-renewable subscriptions. 
Current status is: app is Ready for sale and All IAPs are approved.

But after I downloaded my app from the App Store I found all IAP icons disappeared and all charged content are free now. While in testing environment, my IAPs works perfectly.

Now 2 days past my IAPs are still not working. I received this email from Apple. Does anyone have any idea of this problem?

“This is a courtesy notice to inform you that although your recently submitted app, xxxxx, includes auto-renewable In-App Purchase subscriptions, it is not eligible for the marketing opt-in incentive.

As a result, the marketing opt-in incentive option will be disabled in iTunes Connect and you will not be able to offer free extensions of auto-renewable In-App Purchase subscriptions in exchange for the right to send marketing materials.”

Comment: Have you found out what the problem was? I'm facing the same at the moment...